# Is it possible to send a hardcoded json response for an ajax request

Tags: jquery

For an ajax request, I want to send a JSON response (hardcoded in a .json file).
Is this possible?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to read from a file and then send that data via ajax?

Comment: Yes, just request the JSON file directly in `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON`

Comment: @techfoobar Can you please guide? how to achieve that?

Comment: I've answered with the basic idea behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your JSON file under

```
<webroot>/data/products.json
```

You can retrieve that file directly via AJAX as:

```
$.getJSON('/data/products.json', function(_products) {
   // iterate thru products here
});
```

If your JSON file is not under , you can use a server side script to read the file and return its contents. For ex: under PHP, that would be:

```
echo file_get_contents(<path-to-json-file>);
```

Comment: Thanks, will try out the mentioned approach